# Floating point formatting in LLDB (debugging C++)

Tags: lldb

Given a `double d`, I can print it,

```
(lldb) expr d
(double) $2 = 3.05658e-08
```

Is there a way to print more digits of d, such as

```
printf("%.15f", d) ?
```

Version of LLDB in question is LLDB-112.2, supplied with OS X 10.7.4

**EDIT:** Using

```
(lldb) expr (int) printf("%.15f", d)
```

results in the process being killed, with a

```
LLVM ERROR: Internal relocations not supported.
```

error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lldb-112.2 is a little old at this point (I think it is about six or seven months old); checking it against the Xcode 4.5 lldb (lldb-167 or so), it looks like it works correctly now.

```
0.000000030565830
Process 77907 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x0000000100000f34 a.out`main + 52 at a.c:6, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    #0: 0x0000000100000f34 a.out`main + 52 at a.c:6
   3    {
   4      double d = .00000003056583;
   5      printf ("%.15f\n", d);
-> 6      return 5;
   7    }
(lldb) p d
(double) $0 = 3.05658e-08
(lldb) expr (int)printf("%.15f\n", d)
(int) $1 = 18
0.000000030565830
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
printf("%.15f", d)
```

?

Comment: I assume you mean `expr (int) printf("%.15f", d)`. In that case, it kills the entire LLDB process with a `LLVM ERROR: Internal relocations not supported.` message. Did anybody see it work on another version of LLDB, maybe?